# Angular.js Novice to Ninja controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I have been trying to learn some Angular.js using Angular.js Novice to Ninja.
The main problem that i have by now is that in the examples you have to files, app.js and controller.js.

The main module is declared in app.js and controllers.js as dependencies:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'myApp.controllers',
'ngRoute'
]);
```

In controllers.js, controllers are declared like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('BookController', function($scope){
$scope.name="Scope for BookController";
});
```

but it never works like that, i have to do this and keep everthing in the same file.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', [
'myApp.controllers',
'ngRoute'
]);
app.controller('BookController', function($scope){
$scope.name="Scope for BookController";
});
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your debugger say?

My guess is you're loading the files in the wrong order. You see, you have to first define `myApp.controllers` to be able to load it in `myApp`, so make sure your `controllers.js` is injected first, and then `app.js`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you load the files in following order in head tag,

```
<script src="/path_to/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/path_to/app.js"></script>
<script src="/path_to_controllers/controllers.js"></script>
```

Also please add following line to the `app.js`,

`myApp.controllers = angular.module('myApp.controllers',[])`

And change your code to following in `controller.js`,

```
myApp.controllers.controller('BookController', function($scope){
   $scope.name="Scope for BookController";
});
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I think the `app.js` needs to be loaded last because it resolves all the dependencies right? But apart from that, this is spot on.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @No1_Melman - You have a valid point but if you will see the code, I have declare `myApp.controllers` in `app.js` thus I have loaded it first.

Comment: Okay, that is a different way of doing it